# Connection to D365 via client credentials works in .net 4.6.2 console app, identical code fails in SSIS script task

Tags: ssis, dynamics-365

After constructing a `Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient` object within an SSIS script task (target server version SQL 2016, VSTA project Target Framework set to 4.6.2), the `IsReady` property is false, and the `CurrentAccessToken` property indicates

> "'client.CurrentAccessToken' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'"

Identical code in a .net 4.6.2 console application works as expected. (Code at end of question).

I can replicate the behaviour in the console application if I construct the `CrmServiceClient` with invalid args for instance URI, client id, or client secret. But I am using exactly the same values in SSIS as I am in the working console application.

As a result of this missing token, when I try to use the client, eg:

```cs
var query = new QueryExpression("account");
var results = client.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

...a null reference exception is thrown at the `RetrieveMultiple` call.

The main difference between the two solutions is that the console app can use nuget packages, whereas the SSIS environment is in VSTA, and references must therefore be added manually. In order to get the correct set of DLLs for the SSIS task I built the console application to generate dlls in that project's bin\Development folder, then referenced those dlls by browsing to them via add-reference within the SSIS VSTA project.

I cannot figure out why SSIS script fails to get a token, whereas the console app succeeds.

Notes:

(1) I am aware that the preferred method of connecting to Dynamics 365 now is with the Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client. However, that nuget package has *many* more dependencies, and causes even bigger problems in the SSIS VSTA environment (such as a dependency on Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions 3.1.8, but when SSIS runs it says it can't find 3.0.0, and telling the VSTA project to generate binding redirects per https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/2931 does not solve the problem)

(2) Adding `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` makes no difference.

(3) [Connection to Microsoft Dynamics 365 working in console app but not in web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65095643/connection-to-microsoft-dynamics-365-working-in-console-app-but-not-in-web-app) Describes the same error, but I am not deploying a web app.

```cs
// console app:

using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using System;

namespace D365Test
{
   internal class Program
   {
      private static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient client = new Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient
         (
            new Uri(@"https://MyOrg.crm6.dynamics.com"),
            @"myClientId",
            @"myClientSecret",
            false,
            null
         );
      }
   }
}

// SSIS script:

public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient client = new Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient
    (
        new Uri(@"https://MyOrg.crm6.dynamics.com"),
        @"myClientId",
        @"myClientSecret",
        false,
        null
    );
    // ...
}
```

Comment: SSIS packages run under a different account (the SQL Server agent or a proxy account), with a different working folder. That account may not be able to save tokens to its cache location. How are you executing the package? Through SQL Server Agent? SSMS? Visual Studio? In VS the package is executed locally, using your account

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The execution environment here is visual studio, it's not yet deployed into the SSIS catalog or being run by SQL agent.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that `Microsoft.Xrm` is a nuget package(s) and if so, those don't "work" with SSIS. See also [SSIS Script: Does not exist in the Namespace - error keeps returning - what am I missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75699245/ssis-script-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-error-keeps-returning-what-am-i/75699388#75699388)

Comment: Right, you can't add a reference to a nuget package in the VSTA environment of SSIS. But you can add a reference to a dll that comes from a nuget package. To do this you can restore the nuget package in some other project (like a console app), build the console app, and go to the bin directory to get the dlls, then reference them from SSIS. As per the question, this is what I did. This works - if it didn't, then the thing wouldn't compile because I am using objects defined in those dlls.